# Bash script to unzip a zip file then cd into it

Tags: regex, bash, unzip

I am trying to create a script that would CD into the file after i run unzip. I've done this for .tar files already but having trouble coming up with the regular expression for the zip. This is the command i run to unzip with force overwrite.

```
unzip -o my_file.zip

Archive:  my_file.zip
inflating: my_file/load.file
inflating: my_file/eccn.txt
inflating: my_file/my_file.tgz
```

Here is what i have tried using `sed`

```
unzip -o my_file.zip | sed "s|/.*$||"
Archive:  my_file.zip
  inflating: my_file
  inflating: my_file
  inflating: my_file
```

Here is how i handle .tar files:

```
tar -xvzf $fname                                        #tar it
topDir=$(tar -xvzf $fname | sed "s|/.*$||" | uniq)      #tars it verbosely and pipes it to uniq
[ $(wc -w <<< $topDir) == 1 ] || exit 1                 #check to see there is one entry in $topDir
cd $topDir                                              #cd into $topDir
echo your current dir is $PWD

tar -xvzf my_file.tgz | sed "s|/.*$||"
my_file
my_file
my_file
my_file
my_file
```

My question is how do i get rid of everything before my_file (e.g infalting: ) and then so i can cd into the extracted file?

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you're asking here. You say "I've done this for .tar files already". Can you post what you've done for tar files that works for you so we can better understand what's being asked?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Why do you need `sed` to enter a directory? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I updated my question of what i did with tar files, I want to do something similar with zip files but the output of zip is different.

Comment: Can you describe the purpose of this? The best solution would be different depending on whether this is to e.g. automate installing tarballs, or for conveniently exploring downloaded archives, or for quickly viewing the contents of a zip.

Comment: I have a another load script that i call after i cd into it and it loads the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is unzip a file an then `cd` into a folder, do just that:

```
unzip my_file.zip; cd my_file
```

It's also worth noting that zip files may contain more than one file or directory at the root level. So in the general case, there isn't exactly one directory to `cd` into. In fact, there could be none at all and it would still be a perfectly valid zip file.

If you're certain that every zip file you're working with has exactly 1 directory, and you want to discover the name of that directory dynamically in code, the following command should get you that directory into a variable so you can `cd` into it:

```
DIR=$(zipinfo -1 my_file.zip | grep -oE '^[^/]+' | uniq)
unzip my_file.zip
cd $DIR
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: Wasn't me, but OP clearly wants to cd to the directory being extracted and not just some random hard coded directory. Ruining the zip contents by putting it all in the current dir is not a solution either.

Comment: As I've stated in my answer, it can't be done in the general case because there is no guarantee that there is exactly one directory to `cd` into. A valid zip file could contain more than one or even zero directories.

Comment: @thatotherguy I've updated my answer to include a solution that gets the name of the folder to `cd` into dynamically, providing there is exactly 1 such folder. I've also removed the `-j` solution now that I have a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I have thought about that, and I quickly deleted my comment before it mislead any readers. It is only helpful in cases where the files in the zip isn't in any directory.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just `grep -m1 /$` because directories will be listed as well?

Comment: @alvits That would work too. There's more than 1 way to skin a cat.